# Pass hexdata to an externam program from PHP

Tags: php, linux, exec, echo, stripslashes

here is my issue:
I wish to pass some hexadecimal data to an external app from PHP:

```
exec('echo "'.$message.'" | /usr/bin/gateway');
```

and $message comes from user input:

> test'"/'\'/"\""//

addslashes(), stripslashes() doesn't solve my troubles.
While using:

```
$message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
```

It the console log I can see:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

or an empty value

So I started thinking, that converting the input to hexadecimal values and passing them could help:

```
exec('echo -e '.$message.' | /usr/bin/gateway');
```

But then I got troubles passing hexadecimal data to that echo.

So my question is how to do that?
I need to pass exactly the same string, that user writes, to the gateway service.
- convert user input to hex form, and put it in the echo -e (how?)
- or somehow fight with the quotations and slashes

Comment: Please tell me you're sanitising the `$message` variable before directly outputting it into an `exec` call. Also, how is `test'"/'\'/"\""//` hexadecimal data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general case, you cannot pass the user input through the shell because of the shell's escaping rules. What you should be doing is getting a handle on the newly spawned process's standard input stream and feed it directly.

You can use [`popen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) to do this:

```
$handle = popen('/usr/bin/gateway', 'w');
fwrite($handle, $_POST['message']);
pclose($handle);
```

If you need to do more than the example shows and `popen` does not provide enough functionality, [`proc_open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) is a more involved and powerful alternative.

**WARNING:** Feeding unfiltered user input to an external process leaves you vulnerable to exploits related to how the process interprets and acts on this input. If your application is accessible to non-trusted users, strongly consider whitelisting the input!

Comment: @Tom: Glad to have helped, even though I wonder how it worked -- I just fixed a very important typo (had `'r'` instead of `'w'`).

Comment: I noticed that one too, ofc with 'r' it wasn't working as intended, but the main thing - using popen instead of exec fixed my headache :-)